# Triggering a Hudson job when all upstream jobs are completed?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I have 3 jobs A,B,C. Job C has upstream Dependency on Job A and Job B. Both Job A and B can run in pararllel. We want that the Job C should only be triggered when Job A and Job B are completed. Is there any existing plug-in that I can use? We are using Hudson 3.0.1

From other posts here I figured out that there is an existing plug-in in Jenkins called Build-Flow Plug-in(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) that provides this functionality. Is there some **plug-in existing in Hudson that provides same functionality** ? Or can I **reuse this plug-in for Hudson** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Build Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin),this may do what you want.

Comment: I think this exists for Jenkins not for Hudson.

Answer (score 0):

Try Multijob Plugin

(https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin)

It provides Multiphase configuration.

If you want to run 2 or more jobs in parallel then put all the jobs in same phase.

In your case you need to create 2 phases

Example:

```
  phase 1:
  job A
  job B
  phase 2:
  job C
```

here phase 2 executes only after the completion of phase 1.